# Enabling device motion manually Aframe 1.0.4

Tags: aframe

I added `device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"` to the a-scene as I wanted to handle the all the popups and loading screens myself.

After I request access to the motion sensors via:

```js
$("#btn_enable").one("click", checkGyro);

function checkGyro() {

    DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(permissionState => {
        if (permissionState === 'granted') {
            window.addEventListener('devicemotion', () => {});
        }
    });
    .catch(console.error);

}
```

The device (iPad iOS 13.4 in mobile viewing mode) shows me the popup requesting access to the motion and orientation sensors which I allow, however the ability to look around the scene is disabled.

What am I missing to get this working?

I get this in the console:

```
webvr-polyfill.js:2584 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 
'i.alpha')
(anonymous) @ webvr-polyfill.js:2584
(anonymous) @ webvr-polyfill.js:2560
(anonymous) @ [native code]:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Request permission has to be triggered by user action like click or a tap. It cannot be initiated by a page without user consent as per browser security and privacy policies.

Comment: Sorry - I updated the exact script flow I'm using above - thanks for your input @DiegoMarcos - I'm seeing the native popup, which lets me allow permissions to the motion controllers.

Comment: Also testing via https on localhost as well as from server just to be sure.

Comment: Been looking at just adjusting the CSS of the existing popup - any idea how I can add to the injected modal?

Also is there a way to manually trigger the popup?

Comment: Think this maybe related to this issue https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4554

Comment: Trying to catch the deviceorientationpermissiongranted too, but it just gets triggered immediately rather than after the "allow" button is pressed

Comment: did you find a solution for this?